# Find the first line having a variable value bigger than a specific number

Tags: linux, awk, text-processing

I have a very huge text file and I want to know how can I find the first line in which the value of a variable is bigger than 1000?

assuming that the variable and its value have only one space in between like this:

```
abcd 24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the first occurrence of `abcd` greater than 1000 and print the line number and matching line and quit:

```
$ awk '$1=="abcd" && $2>1000{print NR, $0; exit}' file
```

To find any variable greater than 1000 just drop the first condition:

```
$ awk '$2>1000{print NR, $0; exit}' file
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the lines in the text file have composed of different formats. So, the abcd variable appears only in some of the lines.

Comment: If you want the first occurrence of any variable *(not just the variable `abcd`)* then just drop the first condition *i.e.* `awk '$2>1000{print;exit}' file`.

Comment: Just a short question: how can I get that line's number??